# Does anyone have a fix for this error code: "[SceneKit] Error: Could not get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)"?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, avplayer

I am currently trying to build an app that will display a 360 video in vr format. The video plays fine when I have it saved as a file inside of the Xcode project. However, the error occurs when I try to play the video from a link to the file stored in dropbox. I am having to play it from a link rather than a file built in to the app as the video is 30mins long so takes up quite a lot of storage. When I try to play the video I am met with a white screen where the video should be and this error code in the title is continuously repeated in the output box. I have seen other posts on here about a similar issue, but none have found an answer as far as I can tell, so I assume other people are looking for answers too. Here is my code to stream the video from Dropbox and generate the AV player:

```
func addARTV() {
        let dropboxVideoURL = URL(string: "VIDEO LINK IN DROPBOX")!
        getVideoDataFromDropbox(url: dropboxVideoURL) { data in
            if let videoData = data {
                let fileURL = self.writeVideoDataToTemporaryFile(videoData: videoData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setupPlayerAndNode(fileURL: fileURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getVideoDataFromDropbox(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                completion(data)
            } else {
                print("Error downloading video data: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func writeVideoDataToTemporaryFile(videoData: Data) -> URL {
        let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4")
        
        do {
            try videoData.write(to: tempURL)
            return tempURL
        } catch {
            print("Error writing video data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return tempURL
        }
    }

    func setupPlayerAndNode(fileURL: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
        
        let tvGeo = SCNSphere(radius:  10)
        tvGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = player
        tvGeo.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        
        tvNode = SCNNode(geometry: tvGeo)
        
        tvGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1), 1, 0, 0)
        
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tvNode)
        sceneView2.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tvNode)
        
        player.play()
        isPlaying = true
    }
```

I have tried using the link to download the video into a local file on the app as the video plays fine when I manually add it to my Xcode project but this gives me the same error. I have tried multiple versions of the code to stream the video but no success. The only information I have found is that it may be an encoding issue but I am relatively new to this and have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Based on the comments in your deleted question, you probably need to put together a [mre] ... it's very difficult to help if we have to spend time trying to guess at what else you might be doing.